# php-ews send calendar invitation

Tags: exchange-server, php-ews

I found lots of examples to send myself a php-ews Exchange calendar invitation, but I have been unable to invite anyone else to my calendar event, even someone I have full access delegate permissions for.  Can you please give a full source example?

I do not have administrator rights on the Exchange system, so I cannot assume their identities.

Erick

Answer (score 2):

By the way, for anyone reading this in the future, this question was solved in an issue on my Github repo, found [here](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/issues/10). I'll post the solution here any way, just in case someone comes across this and has a similar issue. Using my [`Garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/) library, the solution is as follows

```
$start = new DateTime('8:01 AM');
$end = new DateTime('9:00 AM');

$createdItemIds = $calendar->createCalendarItems(array(
    'Subject' => 'Test',
    'Start' => $start->format('c'),
    'End' => $end->format('c'),
    'RequiredAttendees' => array(
        array(
            'Mailbox' => array(
                'Name' => 'Person 1',
                'EmailAddress' => 'first@email.com',
            )
        ),
        array (
            'Mailbox' => array(
                'Name' => 'Person 2',
                'EmailAddress' => 'second@email.com'
            )
        )
    )
), array('SendMeetingInvitations' => 'SendOnlyToAll'));
```